# Hundreds of thousands of folders in Windows 10 user temp folder

Tags: process, malware, user-folders, malware-detection

I noticed last week it took a while to open a group of PDFs on my computer. I had a look in %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp and I found well over 800,000 folders. I had to delete them with a for loop because there were so many. I don't recall the %temp% folder size at the time.

Tonight, about a week later, I noticed the same behavior and I again have 819,000 folders, and climbing at about one new folder per second . Disk space of my %temp% folder is only about 300MB. The folder naming convention matches `????????-????-4???-????-????????????` (yes that one char is always a '4'), or for my fellow RegEx people, `[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-4[0-9a-f]{3}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{12}`. Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Can anyone point me toward some system monitoring software where I can see what's creating these folders?

After a reboot, executing `dir /a:d /b ????????-????-4???-????-???????????? | wc -l` shows there are 818,666 folders and holding.

Answer (score 0):

Gads.  This is a new one on me.  So let's start with the basics.

The one thing you know is that temp files can be safely deleted unless they are in use.  So a fresh reboot is the time to clean them out.  Maybe safe mode would be even better.

If you are having trouble with getting Windows to do the job, you can boot up a Linux LiveCD and use the rm -r command on that directory, empty your trash, then recreate the directory.

Then I suggest you run Malwarebytes to see if it finds any cause for this.

Comment: Gads indeed. Using `rm -r *` would probably fail with that long of a list. I'm using `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /a:d /b 0???????-????-????-????-????????????') do (rmdir /s /q "%a")` (where I replace '0' with successive hex chars) to remove the folders. And the problem with recreating the temp directory is the index attribute. If you don't set it to not index, the OS will index the directory. One thing my co-worker learned the hard way.